# Is there a way to have an image always fit the div it is in with over flow in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a div on my page that takes up two-thirds of the width and 95% of the viewport's height. I plan on having images that take up the entire div with an aspect ratio of 21:9. I have the div set to overflow: hidden; which means that the left and right part is cut out. This works fine until you get to screens with aspect ratios such as 32:9 where the div is wider than the image. I wonder if there is a clean solution which makes the top / bottom of the image cut out when this occurs.

```
HTML:

<figure>
    <a
        href="images/slideshow/00_stellaris_acot.png"
        data-lightbox="ui_overhaul_dynamic"
    >
        <img src="images/slideshow_source/00_stellaris_acot.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a
        href="images/slideshow/01_delta.png"
        data-lightbox="ui_overhaul_dynamic"
    >
    </a>
    <a
        href="images/slideshow/02_alpha.png"
        data-lightbox="ui_overhaul_dynamic"
    >
    </a>
</figure>

CSS:

body > main > section > figure {
  background-color: rgb(10, 12, 54);
  border-style: none solid none none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body > main > section > figure > a > img {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior by using the `object-fit` property in CSS. It specifies how the contents of a replaced element should be fitted to the box established by its used height and width.

With `object-fit: cover`, the image will cover the entire container while preserving its aspect ratio, cutting off any overflow:

```
body > main > section > figure > a > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Or you can set `object-fit: contain`, and the image will fit inside the container while preserving its aspect ratio, showing all parts of the image:

```
body > main > section > figure > a > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It does exactly what I wanted it to without any issues.